# Default behaviour when missing argument in \newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'll try to be clear because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812224/2935371) is not what I am looking for.

What I'm trying to do is to define a new command that takes one argument but has a different behaviour whether that argument is or is not specified.

Here's what I have so far :

```
\newcommand\Nk[1][k]{N_{#1}}
```

I want to be able to get :

- [image: nk] if I enter `\Nk`
- [image: ni] if I enter `\Nk{i}`

For now, with that second option I just get [image: nik].

So here's my question : how can I get that behaviour I want ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use square brackets: `$\Nk[i]$` in the invocation.  Square brackets are used for *optional* arguments, which is the way you have defined `\Nk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of `\newcommand` is that optional arguments are provided in square brackets `[]` and mandatory arguments are provided in curly braces `{}`.

It is a newbie mistake to forget it, but it can be frustrating to find when it happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Nk[1][k]{N_{#1}}
\begin{document}
    $N_k$ if I enter $\Nk$\par
    $N_i$ if I enter $\Nk[i]$\par
    but not $\Nk{i}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]